# Unable to upgrade to 22.04

Tags: upgrade

This is a 21.10 server that only runs plex and hardly ever gets touched.  I tried to update the plex server and was greeted with "The repository 'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security Release' no longer has a Release file." when I try to run apt-update.  Doing research I found that this is because 21.10 went EOL.  I have also read that I need to run do-release-upgrade.  When I run that I get the following

> Checking for a new Ubuntu release
> Your Ubuntu release is not supported anymore.
> For upgrade information, please visit:
> http://www.ubuntu.com/releaseendoflife
> Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading.

How do I install all available updates for my current release when I can't do apt update or upgrade because I am not on 22.04, but can't get 22.04 because I need the updates that I can't get.  Circle logic is real lol.

Any help?

Comment: It DID!  Thank you!  Was starting to think I had lost my mind lol

Comment: Announcements were sent out six weeks prior to EOL; as well as at/after EOL (eg. https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/06/01/ubuntu-21-10-impish-indri-reaches-end-of-life-on-july-14-2022/ https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/07/19/ubuntu-21-10-impish-indri-end-of-life-reached-on-july-14-2022/) which included instructions (via link) on the upgrade to *jammy*. Being EOL you had another step now which is required first and is covered at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades   21.10 told you it was the 2021-October release so adding 9 months from that alone tells you the EOL month for planning...

Comment: There is no set *date* on which the archive move occurs; except it's documented to occur **after** the EOL date; some releases occur the subsequent day (eg. 17.04), some a couple of days, some occur later..  If you miss EOL warning/notices, you can look at the initial release announcements & it'll not be before that date, and usually on that date or the Thursday after it (Ubuntu releases are scheduled for Thursdays).